# Heroku: delayed job sending email multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

We have one application(Rails 3) deployed in Heroku.
For sending email digest to nearly about 500 users, we are using delayed_job.

```
Notifier.delay.send_email_digest(digest_content, @user)
```

My application has 3 web dynos and 2 worker dynos.
Though the task is sending only one Email digest per user in local, 
In heroku (production) it's sending two email digests for some users (strange).

Is it due to two worker dynos (but why?? or mere coincidence).
Can anybody help me solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the problem when you only have one worker?

Comment: @Neil Middleton we need two worker dynos to make some other background jobs. So, can u help me figure out where it goes wrong?

Comment: My guess is that a job is being picked up by each worker which are then subsequently working the job twice.

Comment: What gem version of delayed_job are you using?  I can't even get it to send a delayed email.

Comment: @asitmoharna did you figure this out? I have the same problem

Answer (score 5):

Within your send_email_digest method are you calling deliver? Delayed Job uses some magic when sending emails and it will automatically call deliver for you. If you call deliver yourself it will send multiple times. I've had this happen on occasion.

Comment: Yes, I found this as well. It's noted in the README: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-3-mailers