# Rails on Heroku Sending Duplicate Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, duplicates, mailer

Client's website is built in Rails 3 and hosted on Heroku, and accepts form submissions which are sent via rails mailers. They are receiving duplicates of emails. I'm unable to replicate the issue in my development environment.

Mail is sent via a gmail account registered to their domain with a standard rails mailer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "clientdomain.com",
  :user_name            => "noreply@clientdomain.com",
  :password             => "password",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

and

```
(gather data)
mail(:to => "staff@clientdomain.com", :subject => "Form Submittal", :from => @email)
```

Duplicates are not necessarily sent instantly, as their delivery varies from 1 minute to over 3 hours after the original.

In some cases HTML characters are replaced with entities.

Here's an example:

```
From: noreply@clientdomain.com
> Subject: Form Submittal
> Date: December 14, 2012 10:38:18 PM EST
> To: staff@clientdomain.com
>=20
> Form Submittal
>=20
> Name: Potential Lead
>=20
> Phone: 1234567890
>=20
> Email: some.user@gmail.com 
>=20
> Message: Hi my names Some I'm from tennesse and I'd really like to =
> get info on your service thank you for all your help!!!
>=20
```

And duplicate:

```
> From: noreply@clientdomain.com
> Subject: Form Submittal
> Date: December 15, 2012 1:46:54 AM EST
> To: staff@clientdomain.com
>=20
> Form Submittal
>=20
> Name: Potential Lead
>=20
> Phone: 1234567890
>=20
> Email: some.user@gmail.com
>=20
> Message: Hi my names Some I%27m from tennesse and I%27d really like =
> to get info on your service thank you for all your help%21%21%21
>=20
```

I was tempted to think the form was just being submitted twice, however the unlikeliness of submitting the exact same input after 3 hours, coupled with the sheer volume of dupes (60-75% reported at times, but never 100%) make me highly skeptical of that.

I also found a gist about duplicate issues which instructed me to override a default setting with this:

```
config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  :arguments => '-i'
}
```

...to no beneficial result.

My question, if not obvious: how to stop rails from sending duplicate emails?

Comment: Did you get any resolution about this? I seem to have a similar problem.

Comment: I did not. It's still sending duplicate emails quite frequently, with no rhyme or reason.

Comment: Huh I am having same problems :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who gets here from google with same problem, here is the solution:
don't use `.deliver` if you use Delayed Job to schedule mailing as originally stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000167/1870446 and here https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-3-mailers

So, instead of `UserMailer.delay.some_mail.deliver` you should use `UserMailer.delay.some_mail`. Cheers!